# How to convert this for loop into an enhanced loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

I have an ArrayList "names" that stores a list of names. For this ArrayList, I need to print all of the names using specifically an enhanced for-loop. How can I make this for-loop an enhanced loop exactly?

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add(0, "Name1");
    names.add(1, "Name2");
    names.add(2, "Name3");

    for (int i = 0; i < (names.size()); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(names.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: Why not first show us your attempt to solve this? Edit -- or not. I guess August spoon fed you the answer. You know you're only cheating yourself by not trying or trying and not showing us your attempt. It's in those attempts where you really learn your Java. <shaking head>

Comment: I tried "for (int i : names)" but I know that I cannot compare the two.

Comment: I created the for-loop, but I could not get down to the enhanced for-loop.

Comment: You haven't shown us that you've tried. But hey, it's your education.

Comment: I'm trying to learn this on my own - it isn't for school or anything. But yes, you have a point. My attempt was the normal for-loop, but I couldn't shift it over as I just learned how to use Arrays.

Comment: They are also known as "for-each" loop.  In fact, that is how you read them: ***FOR EACH*** [Data type] ***IN*** [collection or array]

Comment: It has nothing to do with school/homework, but showing your efforts always helps. It also forces you to focus your mind on the problem to a much greater degree than if you didn't first give it a try. I really think that it makes a difference in how we learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [Java for-loop tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

```
for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

You can use this syntax on any array type, or class that implements [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

You cannot do `for (int i : names)` because the type of the variable on the left side of the colon must be assignable from the `Iterable`'s generic type. (Or the array component type, if you're using an array).

An `ArrayList<String>` implements `Iterable<String>`, so the variable to the left of the colon must be assignable from `String`, which `int` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
for(String name:names){
 System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[An enhanced loop has this structure](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)

```
for (String element : array) {
    System.out.println("Element: " + element);
}
```